# Sum rows where index steps is not bigger than 1. Pandas Python

Tags: python

I have foot sensor data and I want to calculate the Std of the swing times.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
       Time     Force 
83      0.83    80
84      0.84    60
85      0.85    40
86      0.86    20
87      0.87    0
88      0.88    0
89      0.89    20
90      0.90    40
91      0.91    60
92      0.92    40
93      0.93    0
94      0.94    0
95      0.95    0
96      0.96    20
```

So to get the times for when the force ==0, I did:

```
df[(df['Force']==0)]
```

Resulting in:

```
       Time     Force 
87      0.87    0
88      0.88    0
93      0.93    0
94      0.94    0
95      0.95    0
```

Now I want to sum the Time per swing.
swing 1 = index 87 + 88, swing 2 = index 93 + 94 + 95

How can I achieve this? How can I sum the rows where the index steps is not bigger than 1?
(Imagine I have thousands of rows to sum)

I tried complicated loops like:

```
swing_durations = []
start = []
start.append(0)
swings_left = swing_times_left.reset_index(drop = True)

for subject in swings_left[['filename']]:
    i = 1
    for time in swings_left['Time'][1:-1]:
        j = i - 1
        k = swings_left.where(swings_left['Time'].loc[i] - swings_left['Time'].loc[j] > 0.01)
        if k == True:    
            start.append(time)
            swing_durations.append(swings_left[['Time']].loc[j] - start[j])
        i = i + 1

    totalswingtime_l['filename'== subject]['Variance'] = swing_durations.std()
```

resulting in an error

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to create an ID for each group of consecutive 0s.

This is what `(df.Force.shift()!=(df.Force)).cumsum()` does.
Afterwards you only keep the groups containing 0s with `np.where`.

```
In [83]: df["swing_id"] = np.where(df.Force==0, (df.Force.shift()!=(df.Force)).cumsum(),np.nan)
    ...: df
Out[83]: 
    Time  Force  swing_id
0   0.83     80       NaN
1   0.84     60       NaN
2   0.85     40       NaN
3   0.86     20       NaN
4   0.87      0       5.0
5   0.88      0       5.0
6   0.89     20       NaN
7   0.90     40       NaN
8   0.91     60       NaN
9   0.92     40       NaN
10  0.93      0      10.0
11  0.94      0      10.0
12  0.95      0      10.0
13  0.96     20       NaN


In [84]: df.groupby("swing_id")["Time"].sum()
Out[84]: 
swing_id
5.0     1.75
10.0    2.82
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```